# Double-Initialisation of values in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt5.7

I have a strange problem, that is burried somewhere within a large project. So far I was not able to reproduce it in a **MCVE**, but as soon as I succeed, I will turn it in.

It is quite a simple missbehavior. Basically I have an `QtObject` with properties, that I set with initial values as such:

**TestObj.qml**

```
QtObject {
    id: root
    property int val1: { console.log('set val', root); return 42 }
    Component.onCompleted: console.log('Constructed Object', this)
}
```

!!! *With this example, I do not reproduce the error* !!!

The output in my project would be now:

> `set val TestObj_QMLTYPE_44(0x33799fa8)`
>   `set val TestObj_QMLTYPE_44(0x33799fa8)`
>   `Constructed Object TestObj_QMLTYPE_44(0x33799fa8)`

So, though the object is only created once, the initial property assignment is performed twice.
As I have no idea, where to look for the culprit, I can't produce a reproducable example, but maybe someone stumbled uppon the same situation already and found a solution.

A solution would be beneficial, as this issue results in multiple instantiations of some objects, that I can not destroy.

Comment: What output do you get if you give the object an `id` and then `print(objectId)` in the property binding? There's also the `QML_DISABLE_DISK_CACHE=1` suggestion, which has helped in the past when things are acting fishy (although I don't know when that was introduced).

Comment: Valid question. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: `QML_DISABLE_DISK_CACHE=1` should have been introduced in `qt5.8` when the JIT started to produce `.qmlc`-files

Comment: I think my findings were a better fit for the *answer*-section than for the *question*-section, though the question remains, whether there is a better solution than the 4 crapy workarounds proposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [**Created Bug-Report:**](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-60746) *maybe they find a way to solve this issue withouth hacky workarounds*

The problem are circular references:

Circular references are resulting in a strange behavior when creating objects.

**TestObj1.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
QtObject {
    property Item paps
    property int myVal: { console.log('myVal'); paps.val }
}
```

**TestObj2.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0    
Item {
    id: root
    property int val: { console.log('set val', root); return 42 }
    Component.onCompleted: console.log('Constructed Object')

    TestObj1 {
        id: to1
        paps: root
    }
}
```

**Result:**

> `qml: myVal`
>   **`qml: set val TestObj_QMLTYPE_4(0x2c0bafb0)`**
>   **`qml: set val TestObj_QMLTYPE_4(0x2c0bafb0)`**
>   `qml: Constructed Object`

The probalbe cause for this is, that the statement `{console.log('set val', root); return 42 }` has not been processed, when it is allready assigned to `myVal`, therefore that statement is executed twice.

While this is no problem in *normal* situations, it might lead to problems, as long as we don't have dynamically created objects in those properties.

**TestObj3.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    id: root
    property QtObject obj: { console.log('set obj'); return objPrototype.createObject(root) }
    Component.onCompleted: console.log('Constructed Object', obj)

    TestObj4 {
        id: to1
        paps: root
    }

    Component {
        id: objPrototype
        QtObject {
            id: op
            Component.onCompleted: console.log('PropertyObject created', op)
        }
    }
}
```

**TestObj4.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
QtObject {
    property Item paps
    property QtObject myObj: paps.obj

    Component.onCompleted: console.log(myObj)
}
```

**Result:**

> `qml: set obj`
>   **`qml: PropertyObject created QObject(0x2c124708)`**
>   `qml: set obj`
>   **`qml: PropertyObject created QObject(0x2c1246f8)`**
>   `qml: Constructed Object QObject(0x2c1246f8)`
>   `qml: QObject(0x2c1246f8)`

So you can see, the object is indeed created twice.

There are some workarounds:

1. *Don't use circular references* - but that would be booring.
2. *Don't use dynamic object creation, as it always produces problems* - I could just create the object, and either use `property alias obj: myObjectID` or `property QtObject obj: myObjectID`. This has the downside, that if the component is reusable, that the user can't replace that object or the object is still created, wasting memory.
3. *Assign the property in `Component.onCompleted` if the property is still empty (not overwritten by the user of the reusable component).* This has the downside, that the object is not available, uppon creation and a lot of `Can't read property ... of null` errors will appear. They will hopefully don't break the app though.
4. *Create a nasty binding loop* Write: `property QtObject obj: (obj ? obj : objPrototype.createObject(root))`. It will throw a warning, but c'mon. It's just a binding loop, that will be detected and broken.

Nothing nice in those workarounds, but maybe something usable.